# Software for employe-like tracking, particular with Email.app?

Tags: software-recommendation, time-tracking

My pal Dave has a number of full and part time employees (all Mac) in sales-like roles.

In short he wanted a

> plugin, or even a separate app that just reads the MBOX file?
>
> To get an idea of
>
> a)  What days emails were sent, (ie days they were working)
>
> b) Times that each email was sent, to see start/stop times.

Essentially, it seems basically "a report on when emails were sent".  (I guess, using Mail.app.)

Can anyone think of something like this?

Or perhaps, at least generally some Mac-focussed employee time tracking (or spying!) thing.

You can imagine it would be quite useful for customer support stuff, you could get reports like...

> Employee 13.  48 emails sent.  1015-1845 hrs

.. etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

[Timing](https://timingapp.com/?lang=en) can help track how much time is spend on different applications (including Mail) and can give quite a breakdown on what a user is doing at that exact moment.

I can't answer to the emails sent, but I imagine it would be far easier to compile such a report using the mail server rather than each individual user's Mail app.

Comment: Hi Christian, thank you for recommending Timing! Daniel, developer of Timing here. In Mail.app, Timing can even track how much time is spent reading a particular email, and while writing an email, time will be attributed to that email's subject. So Dave could use Timing to track the time spent working on emails with particular subjects, and he can of course also see when exactly (and for how long) those emails were edited.

Comment: Hi @MrMage - thanks; It's a great app and everyone should have it.  One issue here, in this example Dave has say four employees, A B C D.  The idea is: A B C and D would have the app on their machines.  And Dave, as the supervisor, on his own machine (web - whatever) would review what A B C D are doing.  (You can imagine Dave doing that at the end of each day or week, say.)  In fact, **is that possible with Timing App?**  I understood it to be only for "you"; it does not upload your results "to your boss"...

Comment: Hi @Fattie, Timing indeed only runs on the local machine, but there are scripts to automatically export data: https://timingapp.com/help/#integrations. Those could then be used to e.g. automatically email reports to Dave.